# Crontab in Linux shell using putty

Tags: linux, shell, cron, putty

This may be very elementary but i am a a beginner when it comes to Linux shell.
I use putty to connect to the server.

I manage to login to the shell just fine. But there doesn't seem to be any option for running crontab commands. 
Do i need to access any other file on the server first?
Like cd /var/spool/cron ?

I want to create a simple cronjob that starts a php file every 10 minutes today:
*/10 * 13 11 2 /PATH/mail.php

I'm blank, but it seems like i could do something like this to create a crontab file.

vi allcron 
crontab allcron

When i do this i get to a new window. What to do here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to execute `crontab -l` first.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the crontab edit/list functions to add/remove your cron jobs.

crontab -e (to edit) opens an editor with the cron jobs. Simply add your statement or append if there are already cronjobs listed: */10 * 13 11 2 /PATH/mail.php

crontab -l to view your cronjobs.

See http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5 for more info or type "man crontab" in your shell for the manual page.

Also note that your user must have privileges to manipulate cronjobs. Typically each user should have access to their own crontab for most cron daemons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The part i actually was looking for was
cd /var/spool/cron so that i could access the crontab.